# Как сделать приветствие

Tags: python, вконтакте

Как сделать приветствие,чтоб когда заходил новый пользователь в беседу вконтакте то бот выдавал ему приветствие,например пришёл новый пользователь и бот говорит добро пожаловать, на пайтоне и через LongPool

Comment: Покажите, что вы пытались сделать, какие есть наработки.

Comment: Ну вот новый участник подключился к беседе в вк и написал своё первое смс и бот отвечает ему что-то